# Display word count in PowerPoint via VSTO / C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto

I'm looking to access the document properties via C# - e.g. Word Count - which is shown in PowerPoint Info / Properties.

Does anybody have an example code how to access those information?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some VB code that demonstrates how the object model works:

```
Sub ShowWords()
    MsgBox ActivePresentation.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of words")
End Sub
```

Unless you're born with intuition that tells you the *internal* name of each property, you might find this useful too ... lists the name of each property:

```
Sub ListProperties()
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To ActivePresentation.BuiltInDocumentProperties.Count
        Debug.Print ActivePresentation.BuiltInDocumentProperties(x).Name
    Next
End Sub
```